# Using QueryClientProvider in a Wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I want to use a single Wrapper Component in a library im providing. The wrapper should provide stuff like Context and QueryClient. The component looks like this:

```
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";

const client = new QueryClient();

function Wrapper(props) {
    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
            {props.children}
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}
```

When wrapping children with the `Wrapper` useQuery throws an error that no QueryClientProvider is set. In this case `App` uses the useQuery Hook from react-query.

```
import { Wrapper } from "my-lib";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Wrapper>
            <App />
        </Wrapper>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

At first i thought you need a QueryClientProvider directly above an useQuery hook. But for example in Storybook you can define one QueryClient for all stories together. Where did i went wrong?

Edit:
App component:

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export const App = () => {
    const data = useQuery("data", () =>
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then((res) =>
            res.json()
        )
    );
    if (data.isError || data.isLoading) return <>Error/Loading</>;
    return <>{data.data.title}</>;
};
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I copied your code exactly and `react-query` is working fine. Can you provide some of your `App` component, maybe the problem is there. Note: I would recommend declaring `client` outside of the function block in case of re-renders, but it is not the cause of the problem here.

Comment: Oh yeah, when i put everything in the same directory it works! I forgot to mention that i want to include the wrapper from a library im providing

Comment: I also tested this locally with no trouble. In your code snippet, `Wrapper` isn't exported, is it exported in your code? (I would expect a different error if it wasn't, but still worth checking). Do you have react devtools installed? In the components tab you should see: Wrapper -> QueryClientProvider -> Context.Provider -> Context.Provider -> App. If you don't then I don't think your Wrapper is rendering.

Comment: my 2cents but shouldn't you initiate     const client = new QueryClient(); outside of a component declaration ? We had it inside before and caused plenty of issue (recreating a client at rerenders and so on). That's also how it's done in the documentation

Comment: @Ivo they definitely should, but it isn't the cause of the problem they are facing.

Comment: Sorry, yea the wrapper is exported. And i moved the QueryClient to outside of the function. The components tab of the react devtools is empty when `App` queries something and `Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one` is thrown. When `App` just returns a string the component tab shows Wrapper -> QueryClientProvider2 -> Context.Provider -> Context.Provider -> App.

Comment: @Pachari That all looks correct, I am stumped why it's throwing the error... Sorry.

Comment: Apparently it is an issue with Vite. This pull request elaborates further https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/3753 . @CalIrvine Thanks anyways for your help!

Comment: @Pachari funny, I was using Vite. Good luck getting it working, I know that `it works on my machine` is an annoying answer, wish I could be more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a few steps lead to my goal:

1. In the library, put `react-query` into the `devDependencies` and `peerDependencies`.
2. In the app, put `react-query` into the `dependencies`.
3. In the library, exclude `react-query` from being bundled by adding it to your bundler config. In my case it's the `vite.config.ts`:

```
const path = require("path");
const { defineConfig } = require("vite");

module.exports = defineConfig({
    build: {
        lib: {
            entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.ts"),
            name: "my-lib",
            formats: ["es", "umd"],
            fileName: "my-lib",
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [
                "react",
                "react-dom",
                "react-query",
            ],         
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather just add a comment somewhere above, but don't have enough reputation to do that. I have to post an answer here to add my 2 cents, hopefully can be helpful to others.

I got the same error "No QueryClientProvider" in my local development environment, wasted lots of time because of the error. My project build system is using yarn1 workspaces + webpack5 (with DLL plugin for creating vendor bundle), which had been working fine for years, until one day got the "No Query..." error without knowing what introduced it. Finally, I found a one line code change solution is to add 'react-query' into the "vendor list" for the DLL plugin.